# No sessions available when refreshing the page

Tags: php, session

I am trying to save the values from input fields in sessions, so when the user can't get through the form validation, the values would be displayed in the input field from the session.

This is how my code looks:

```
function data_setter($name) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }
}

function show_form() {
    return '
        <h1>E-Mail-Vorbereitung<br /><br /></h1>
        <form action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="anrede">Anrede</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="anrede" id="anrede" class="staff_form">
                            <option id="select" disabled selected> -- Wähle eine Option -- </option>
                            <option id="frau" value="frau">Frau</option>
                            <option id="herr" value="herr">Herr</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="name">Name</label>
                    <td><input value="' . data_setter('receiver') . '" type="input" class="staff_form" name="receiver" id="name" placeholder="Name des Empfängers eingeben" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="email">E-Mail</label></td>
                    <td><input value="' . data_setter('email') . '" type="input" class="staff_form" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail des Empfängers eingeben" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br /><input name="sent" type="submit" value="Daten prüfen" />
        </form>
    ';
}

function mailsender() {
    if (isset($_POST['sent']) &&
        isset($_POST['anrede']) && !empty($_POST['anrede']) &&
        isset($_POST['receiver']) && !empty($_POST['receiver']) &&
        isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])
    ) {
        if (!is_email($_POST['email'])) {
            $_SESSION['receiver'] = $_POST['receiver'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            var_dump($_SESSION);

            echo '
                <h1>Error</h1>
                <p>Die eingegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist nicht gültig. Hast du dich vielleicht vertippt?</p>
                <FORM>
                    <INPUT TYPE="submit" onClick="window.location.href = "' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '";" VALUE="Nochmals probieren">
                </FORM>
            ';
        }
        else {
            // Delete sessions
            if (isset($_SESSION['anrede'])) { unset($_SESSION['anrede']); }
            if (isset($_SESSION['receiver'])) { unset($_SESSION['receiver']); }
            if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { unset($_SESSION['email']); }

            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = "yc_customers";
            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") == $table_name) {
                $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT email FROM yc_customers" );
                foreach ($myrows as $myrow) {
                    // Doing sumth here

                }
            }
            echo '
                <h1>Daten valid</h1>
                <p>Super, die Daten wurden geprüft und die Firma ist in der Your-Click-Datenbank <strong>nicht vorhanden</strong>.</p>
            ';
        }
    }
    else {
        // Set sessions
        if (isset($_POST['receiver']) && !empty($_POST['receiver'])) { $_SESSION['receiver'] = $_POST['receiver']; }
        if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) { $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']; }

        // Validating
        if ($_POST['sent']) {
            // Anrede
            if (!isset($_POST['anrede']) || empty($_POST['anrede'])) {
                echo '
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        Bitte wähle eine Anrede aus.
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            // Receiver
            if (!isset($_POST['receiver']) || empty($_POST['receiver'])) {
                echo '
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        Bitte gebe den Namen des Empfängers ein.
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            // E-Mail
            if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
                echo '
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        Bitte gebe die E-Mail-Adresse des Empfängers ein.
                    </div>
                ';
            }
        }
        echo show_form();
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        // Set the chosen option
        if (isset($_POST['anrede']) && !empty($_POST['anrede'])) {
            echo '<script>$("#select").prop("selected", false);</script>';
            if ($_POST['anrede'] == 'frau') {
                echo '<script>$("#frau").prop("selected", true);</script>';
            }
            elseif ($_POST['anrede'] == 'herr') {
                echo '<script>$("#herr").prop("selected", true);</script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('mailsender', 'mailsender');
```

When I type anything in the email field and the email is NOT valid, var_dump shows me all the sessions correctly but when I click on the button "Nochmals probieren" to get back to the form page, var_dump tells me NULL. Where are my sessions at??

Comment: where is your session_start() call?

Comment: @Florian well, I guess that's the point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a session_start() call somewhere. And your data_setter function is kind of pointless, since you could just do $_SESSION['whatever'] directly.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe that I really missed that. This is awkward. But thanks for the advice about the data_setter function. I didn't know that it is not necessary to check if a session is set.

Answer (score 1):

have you started your session session_start();

Answer (score 1):

I seems that you are using session_start() in your form page only.Use the `session_start()` in the pages at the top of your PHP page before any code start where your form is getting submitted. I hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for completness, my comment as an answer: You missed a session_start() call before you try to save/read data from a session the first time (usually as one of the first setup steps of your entry point script.

Answer (score 0):

Start Session in required page, session_start();